# Autoresizing UITableViewCell with UITextView which has text aligned to vertical center simultaneously?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell, uitableviewautomaticdimension

Cell contains multiline text so I decided to use text view.

`textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero` removes extra padding. Code to center it vertically:

```
extension UITextView {
    func centerVertically() {
        var topCorrect = (self.bounds.size.height - self.contentSize.height * self.zoomScale) / 2
        topCorrect = topCorrect < 0.0 ? 0.0 : topCorrect;
        self.contentInset.top = topCorrect
    }
}
```

This works if I predefine cell height in `tableView(_:, heightForRowAt:)`.

But if I use `UITableView.automaticDimension` to resize the cell everything becomes broken.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: You definitely shouldn't extend `UITextView` for this. This is not a good use case for extensions. You should also be using auto layout for basically all of your positioning, especially for self-sizing cells (how else are they supposed to self size, right?). I would remove the extension and implement auto layout in your cell and all of your problems will disappear.

Comment: Don't use `UITextView` only for having multiline. Use `UILabel` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use auto layout and pin leading, trailing, top and bottom, constraints of textview to the cell.
2. Disable scrolling in textview
3. Add a height constraint such that height is greater than or equal to a constant value (this is a min value that will show on the screen) for textview
4. User .automatic dimension

Try this and let me know if this worked out for you